# Connecting CPE to Cisco catalyst switch

Tags: cisco, network, ip-address

I have a set of cisco catalyst switches, that are configured with vlan 10.10.1.0 and 10.10.0.0. I have a CPE from my provider, which is configured with the following information:

Network: 10.0.30.8/30
Gateway: 10.0.30.9
CPE: 10.0.30.10

How can i connect these devices, so that i can access the CPE from my workstations, configured with the addresses from the 10.10.0.0 and .1 networks?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options:

- configure a local route on each host (computer) so the traffic to the VPN goes to the CPE. This is bad solution.
- add a route on your firewall so it redirect traffic to the CPE. This is the simplest solution.
- use Layer 3 switches, configure them as the gateway for your local networks, add a route for the Internet to your firewall and another route for the VPN to the CPE. This has some advantages in term of performance, but if your switch are not already Layer3 capable, include additional costs.

Comment: I'm trying to do option 3. I have on my static routing: destination 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 gateway 10.10.10.254. I've tried setting another route as destination 10.0.30.0 mask 255.0.0.0 gateway 10.0.30.9 but it doesn't work (no error is specified)

Answer (score 0):

Configure the Gateways of VLAN 10.10.1.0 and 10.10.0.0 on CPE, by connecting the catalyst switches to CPE and you are done :)

Comment: I can't, the gateway to these vlans is my firewall, which then goes to the internet. The CPE is going to be used for another VPN, which is not used in the public internet.

Comment: Add a VLAN via your switch from firewall to new CPE, Plus you have to route packets towards CPE from firewall for the segments on VPN(So static routes should be configured)... Can that be done?

Comment: I would like to try to avoid messing with the firewall, as it's only going to add more steps. I just want to connect the CPE to my lan.

Comment: Well In any case you have to add routes to the VPN segments on firewall. So either you can follow the solution above. Or you can give the CPE interface an IP from the existing VLANs(10.10.1.0 and 10.10.0.0) and route packets towards that IP... Or switch IP of clients when they want to access the CPE(which is not practical).

Comment: Can't i route the traffic from my lan with the following rules? Something that has a destination of 10.0.30.0 goes to the CPE, others have a destination of 10.10.10.254 (firewall)

Answer (score 0):

Connect the CPE to a layer 3 switch. Configure the layer 3 switch with the following:

Default route to the Firewall
add another route to the 10.0.30.0 network.

Comment: What switch models do you have? And do you have any experience in configuring routing?